# Python iterating through object attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, for-loop

How do I iterate over an object's attributes in Python?

I have a class:

```
class Twitt:
    def __init__(self):
        self.usernames = []
        self.names = []
        self.tweet = []
        self.imageurl = []

    def twitter_lookup(self, coordinents, radius):
        cheese = []
        twitter = Twitter(auth=auth)
        coordinents = coordinents + "," + radius
        print coordinents
        query = twitter.search.tweets(q="", geocode=coordinents, rpp=10)
        for result in query["statuses"]:
            self.usernames.append(result["user"]["screen_name"])
            self.names.append(result['user']["name"])
            self.tweet.append(h.unescape(result["text"]))
            self.imageurl.append(result['user']["profile_image_url_https"])
```

Now I can get my info by doing this:

```
k = Twitt()
k.twitter_lookup("51.5033630,-0.1276250", "1mi")
print k.names
```

I want to be able to do is iterate over the attributes in a for loop like so:

```
for item in k:
   print item.names
```

Comment: what attributes ? you mean over 'k' attributes?

Comment: I may not be using the proper terminology here but yes I want to be able to have my usernames, tweets, etc. returned in some sort of object that i can iterate through them individually. like so: for item in twitter print item.usernames. Something along those lines.

Comment: try my answer and see if works for you.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

UPDATED

For python 3, you should use `items()` instead of `iteritems()`

**PYTHON 2**

```
for attr, value in k.__dict__.iteritems():
        print attr, value
```

**PYTHON 3**

```
for attr, value in k.__dict__.items():
        print(attr, value)
```

This will print

```
'names', [a list with names]
'tweet', [a list with tweet]
```

Comment: k.iteritems() was removed in Python3, use k.items() instead.

Comment: @trdavidson I added the note.

Comment: Also new in python3 you need parens for the print operation.

Comment: Hidden `__dict__` method very useful! 
Also, to return as a dict use a dict comprehension `print({attr:value for attr, value in k.__dict__.iteritems()})`

Comment: I tried this on an object which is inheriting from another one, and it only returned the properties belonging to the base class.

Comment: This works if and only if the object has a `__dict__` attribute. This is [not always true](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots), and you should iterate through `__slots__` if it doesn't.

Answer (score 46):

You can use the standard Python idiom, [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#vars):

```
for attr, value in vars(k).items():
    print(attr, '=', value)
```

Answer (score 9):

### Iterate over an objects attributes in python:

```
class C:
    a = 5
    b = [1,2,3]
    def foobar():
        b = "hi"    

for attr, value in C.__dict__.iteritems():
    print "Attribute: " + str(attr or "")
    print "Value: " + str(value or "")
```

Prints:

```
python test.py
Attribute: a
Value: 5
Attribute: foobar
Value: <function foobar at 0x7fe74f8bfc08>
Attribute: __module__
Value: __main__
Attribute: b
Value: [1, 2, 3]
Attribute: __doc__
Value:
```