# How can an instance be iterated over?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iteration, instance, self

In [datatstructures.py](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/datastructures.py), there is a method `values()`:

```
def values(self):
    """Iterate over all values."""
    for item in self:
        yield item[0]
```

`self` is an instance of the class; how can it be iterated over?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python iterating through object attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150955/python-iterating-through-object-attributes)

Comment: Not a duplicate. My question is not *How to* but rather *How can* (as in: how can it be possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, it has to implement `__iter__` method, e.g.

```
class Test:
    def __iter__(self):
        yield 1
        yield 2

>>> instance = Test()
>>> for val in instance:
...     print val
...
1
2
```

Answer (score 2):

The class which the given method belongs to extends `ImmutableList` which is iterable, thus the method can iterate on the class.

Comment: What defines `ImmutableList` as iterable? I see now `__iter__` method.

Answer (score 1):

If the object in question is [Iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) it can be iterated. This is how lists, dicts, and other sequences are designed.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is not How to but rather How can (as in: how can it be possible)

`self` refers to the actual tangible object you deal with, `classes` are more like their interface (don't interpret this too strictly); if an instances' class defines a `__iter__` (or `__getitem__`) method they can be iterated over in a `for` loop. **[PEP 234](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/)** deals with the semantics and implementation of iterators.

In your specific case the *function* is a **generator** which *has nothing to do with the `__iter__` method*, it simply transforms the `values` function to a generator in order to support iteration of the form:

```
for i in instance.values(): # do stuff
```

If the object doesn't define an `__iter__` it won't be able to be iterated over, as an example:

```
class myfoo:
    def func(self):
        for i in range(10): yield i

f = myfoo()
```

The instance `f` is now **not** iterable:

```
for i in f: print(i) # TypeError
```

On the other hand, we can use `func` in a `for` loop:

```
for i in f.func(): print(i, end=" ")
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Changing `func` to `__iter__` changes the picture, now the instance `f` **is** iterable:

```
class myfoo:
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(10): yield i

f = myfoo()
```

Iterating through `f` is done intuitively with:

```
for i in f: print(i, end=" ")
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

---

Asking why, as in, how can this be possible is like asking why can strings be multiplied with `"s" * 4`. This is the way things were implemented because it just made sense as a way of handling the common case of looping through the contents of a container. Don't overthink things, it isn't necessary.

Comment: @Pyderman You're welcome, good for you for digging in the source code of projects and trying to understand how they work.