# How to loop through object fields in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to loop through the object fields to update their values but im not quite sure how to do this.

```
class FinancePending(models.Model):
invoiceNumber = models.IntegerField
amountPaid = models.CharField(max_length=20)
AmountPending = models.IntegerField( blank=True, null=True)
TotalAmount = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0)
```

Now i want to calculate amountpending in a function. But its not working

```
     amount_paid = FinancePending.objects.values_list('amountPaid', flat=True)
        amount_paid = list(amount_paid)
        total_amount = FinancePending.objects.values_list('TotalAmount', flat=True)
        total_amount = list(total_amount)

        # total - paid
        TotalFee = [float(s.replace(',', '')) for s in total_amount]
        AmountPaid = [float(s.replace(',', '')) for s in amount_paid]
        finance_pending = FinancePending.objects.all()
        i = 0
        while i < len(TotalFee):
            amount_pending = TotalFee[i] - AmountPaid[i]
            FinancePending.objects.filter(invoiceNumber=i).values(AmountPending=amount_pending)
            setattr(finance_pending, 'AmountPending', str(amount_pending))
            i = 1 + i
```

Comment: Give a detailed explanation on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150955/python-iterating-through-object-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would suggest using [Query Expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/), more powerful and robust